# UWP: Button without ControlTemplate behaving different than with one

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Probably, I'm understanding something fundamentally wrong, but according from what I've read, the ControlTemplate-Property allows me the completely define the appearance of a Control without changing its logic like Events etc.

For some testing, I created an empty UWP-Project, and created a Button with stretch:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Background="Red">
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

As expected, the Button stretches trough the whole Window.
Now, I overwrite the Template with basically exact the same Button, but as Template:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        Background="Red" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

In this case, the HorizontalAlignment gets ignored.
Since I overwrite the appearance of an Button with basically the Default-Button Template, a Button, I'd have expected the same behavior. I can fix it by defining the HorizontalAlignment on the Button itself and then use TemplateBinding, but I don't get why it's not just overwritten as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the default template for a Button, it's essentially this (with some stuff like visual states omitted):

```
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter/>
</Grid>
```

And inspecting the button in the Live Visual Tree confirms this:

[image: Screenshot]

So you see that the Grid doesn't *replace* the Button element, the Button is still a Button in the visual tree, rather the template defines what the immediate child of the Button will be.

If you set the template to the following:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red"/>
```

then you'll get this visual tree:

[image: Screenshot]

The reason why the HorizontalAlignment doesn't work in this way is because it is applied to the inner Button and not the outer button. As part of the layout process, the outer Button (the parent) is what determines the size and location of the inner Button (the child), and since the parent isn't stretched, it can only accommodate the smallest size necessary to display the child.

It's like you're trying to do this:

```
<Grid>
    <Button>
        <!-- This button won't stretch to the width of the Grid -->
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Button>
</Grid>
```

It doesn't make sense to set the Template of a Button to a Button. It looks like what you want to do is to set a Style instead, then you can have a setter for the Template and the HorizontalAlignment of the parent.

```
<Style x:Name="MyCustomButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                ....
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you want to tweak the template of a control, you can right click it in the XAML designer > Edit Template > Edit a Copy. This will pull in the default style for that control into your Page which you can then modify.

---

**EDIT**

> So, every Control, even without Template, has an appearance in the VisualTree and thus needs to be targeted?

I'm not sure what you mean by "targeted", but yes, every Control and Control-derived class has a Template which can be specified. Every Control has a [default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.defaultstylekey.aspx) which sets the Template for the control (among other properties). I refer you to [Default control styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299122.aspx) if you're interested in these styles.

> The Template then only overrides the "Content" of the Control?

No. The Content of a [ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) (such as a Button) is different from the Template. Think of the Template as defining the entire visual appearance of the control, and the Content as defining only a subset of the appearance within the template somewhere. When you set the Content of a Button, for example, you're not changing the entire appearance of the button (the button still has a border and background), you only changed what's displayed inside the button at some particular point within the button's visual tree. It is the [ContentPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) control (refer to my first screenshot) which displays the content.

> I didn't know I can see the Visual Tree, do I need a special version or such for that?

Visual Studio has had the Live Visual Tree feature for a while now (at least since 2015), so you should have that feature unless you have an outdated version of Visual Studio.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to test the behavior with my "Button in Button" approach. So, every Control, even without Template, has an appearance in the VisualTree and thus needs to be targeted? The Template then only overrides the "Content" of the Control?
I didn't know I can see the Visual Tree, do I need a special version or such for that?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller: The *Live Visual Tree* as well as the *Live Property Explorer* are built into Visual Studio 2015 (any edition), as explained under [Inspect XAML properties while debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx).

Comment: @MatthiasMüller I've edited my answer regarding your comments.

Comment: how can we achieve this logic in C# code behind, like Style, Setter property Template